# How to add a new key:value pair to an already existing array state variable react native

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native, expo

I have a database function that returns some rows from a sqlite database then stores that in state

```
rows = await ReturnSelectedSymbolsDB()
this.setState({ symbols: rows })
```

The array looks something like this

```
symbols: [{key: "0", symbol:"name1", active: false},{key:"1", symbol:"name2",active: false}]
```

I have another database function which returns some rows and I wish to add them to `symbol` so it would look like this.

```
symbols: [{key: "0", symbol:"name1", active: false, newKey: newValue},{key:"1", symbol:"name2",active: false, newKey, newValue2}]
```

The second function will return multiple rows from the database which will be easy to match up with `symbols` as symbols:symbol will match otherFunction:symbol.

Normally you would just write this like a regular SQL query with a inner join joining the 2 tables together and then just putting the resulting rows in a state variable but I cannot in this case and must build the state variable piece by piece.

Can this be done is regular javascript?

EDIT:
Probably wasnt clear but `newKey` can have different values depending on what the name of the `symbol` is

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new util function where you can add new key to all object inside the array.

```
addKey(symbol) {
   let newArray=[...symbol];
   return newArray.map((ele, i) => {
      return {...ele, newKey: newValue};
   })
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I do want to add a new key to all objects in the array, but each value that pertains to the new key will be different. Will your code do this?

Comment: Yes it will work.. Just send map function and pass new key with new value with object which you want to have new key- value pair.

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert your new value into your first function array, there are couples of way can insert object in array either use **for loop** or array **manipulation** functions.

```
var arrOfObj = [{
  key: "0", 
  symbol:"name1", 
  active: false
}, {
  key: "1", 
  symbol:"name1", 
  active: false
}, {
  key: "2", 
  symbol:"name1", 
  active: false
}];

var result = arrOfObj.map(function(o) {
  o.newKey = newValue;
  return o;
})

console.log(result)
```

> Note: I would prefer to go with inner join with two tables to return
>   combine array that not require any array manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you know the key value corresponding to a given symbol:

```
for (let i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++){
    symbols[i].newKey = "anyValue"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
let symbols = [
  { key: "0", symbol: "name1", active: false },
  { key: "1", symbol: "name2", active: false }
];
let newSymbols = [
  { key: "1", symbol: "name1", newKey: "fdds" },
  { key: "0", symbol: "name2", newKey: "sadav" }
];

mergeArray = (arrayOld, arrayNew) => {
  let output = arrayOld.filter(item => {
    let find = findMatchingItem(arrayNew, item.key);
    item["newKey"] = find.newKey;
    return item;
  });
  return output;
};

findMatchingItem = (array, matchingItemKey) => {
  let output = null;
  array.map(item => {
    if (item.key == matchingItemKey) {
      output = item;
    }
  });
  return output;
};

let newArray = mergeArray(symbols, newSymbols);
console.log(newArray);
```

I have matched objects using `"key"` if you want from `"symbol"` just change `"key"` to `"symbol"`